# Callback before create index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my workflow, I have created a unique index combined with three columns of my `Invoices (:company_id, :forwarder_id, :forwarder_reference)`. And I would like to run a callback before it save the index associated to my element to avoid AR errors.

My code :

```
    validate :forwarder_reference_uniqness

    def forwarder_reference_uniqness
      dup_invoices = Invoice.where(
        company_id: company_id,
        forwarder_id: forwarder_id,
        forwarder_reference: forwarder_reference
      )
      errors.add(:forwarder_reference, :uniqueness) if dup_invoices && dup_invoices.where.not(id: id).any?
    end
```

And I still have the error of uniqueness of my index while the validate method is generating an error

My error :

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '61-9514-12345' for key
'uniq_forwarder_ref_on_forwarder_invoices' excluded from capture: DSN
not set
 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry
'61-9514-12345' for key 'uniq_forwarder_ref_on_forwarder_invoices'):
```

So do you know a way to stop the process if a validate error is generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use a Rails `uniqueness` validation with a `scope` like this?

```
# in app/models/invoice.rb
validate :forwarder_reference, uniqueness: { scope: %i[company_id forwarder_id] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the error is still appearing ;)

Comment: How is the index `uniq_forwarder_ref_on_forwarder_invoices` actually defined?